# How do we get a JWT bearer grant with required audience?

Tags: oauth, jwt

According to the [OAuth JWT Bearer grant spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer-12#section-3.1), a valid JWT should have some sort of identifier (token endpoint may be used) of the token issuing authorization server within the audience claim.

> The JWT MUST contain an "aud" (audience) claim containing a
> value that identifies the authorization server as an intended
> audience.  The token endpoint URL of the authorization server
> MAY be used as a value for an "aud" element to identify the
> authorization server as an intended audience of the JWT.  The
> Authorization Server MUST reject any JWT that does not contain
> its own identity as the intended audience In the absence of an
> application profile specifying otherwise, compliant applications
> MUST compare the audience values using the Simple String
> Comparison method defined in Section 6.2.1 of RFC 3986
> [RFC3986].  As noted in Section 5, the precise strings to be
> used as the audience for a given Authorization Server must be
> configured out-of-band by the Authorization Server and the
> Issuer of the JWT.

So how can we obtain a JWT with our required audience claim from an IDP to be used as a JWT bearer grant? Is it valid to use OpenID token as a JWT bearer grant?

Comment: Okay, after a bit of searching found this https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-tschofenig-oauth-audience-00 with the help of a colleague.